# A method to visually separate text lines in Richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I would like to know if there is an easier way to add any kind of visual separation like a line between text lines in a Richtextbox?
If not, is there another component that I can use in a Form that would be able to do this for text lines?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a few years, but at one point I wrote a RichTextBox wrapper that ended up manipulating the underlying markup.  It wasn't pretty and it wasn't for the faint of heart, but it did work.  I ended up using it to highlight some text I believe.

The key thing you need to know is the specification for the RTF markup language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format should get you started.

The [RichTextBox class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx) and the **[Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document.aspx)** property should get you started at modifying the underlying structure of the document after loading or during editing.